# How to update touch points for S2240T touchscreen monitor on Raspberry PI 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, touchscreen

I am using a Dell S2240T touch screen with a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspberry Pi OS version 12. In normal orientation mode, touch points work fine, but when rotated, touch points do not align.